# Usage Pool in C#

Tags: c#

In one of the interviews of C#, the guy was asking me are you aware of usagepool in C#.

I asked him is it thread pool that he is talking about, but he said no it is usage Pool

He was giving the hint that we can reuse the same thing without destroying using something like usage pool

Any idea what the guy might be talking about?

Comment: There is a pattern, the [object pool pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern). But it's another thing. And in the advantages of GC languages is the one that they are very fast at allocating memory because they can reuse memory allocated for the same object type (if that object has been finalized).

Comment: Maybe the guy wanted to swim or something :-) But `usage Pool` seems weird as terminology.

Comment: @xanatos: I was wracking my brains trying to remember what that pattern was called :)

Comment: @uday Pro Tip: When the interview is over, *ask the interviewer about any questions you couldn't answer*. What's the worst that could happen?

Comment: My thought: he used the wrong words (usage pool instead of object pool) and he didn't notice it. Even interviewers are only human.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe object pooling?

Object Pooling service enables you to reduce the overhead of creating each object from scratch. When an object is activated, it is pulled from the pool. When the object is deactivated, it is placed back into the pool to await the next request.

Or was he possible talking about an application pool?  Where an application pool will not be affected by application problems in other application pools.

Answer (score 1):

It might have been to determine if you ever BS.

In which case the correct answer is, "I've never heard of that."

Answer (score 0):

He may have referred to an Inversion of Control.
You can find a basic implementation here: [IoC](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/IoC.aspx)

If you're looking for more in-depth stuff, i recommand MEF (which is a dependency injection as well, and ships with .NET), Unity, Castle Windsor...

**EDIT** - Comments asked for clarification:

> He was giving the hint that we can reuse the same thing without destroying using something like usage pool

Looks a lot like IoC to me.

Comment: I'm guessing that Baboon is referring to the pooled component lifestyle that some containers support, for instance Castle Windsor (http://www.castleproject.org/container/documentation/trunk/usersguide/lifestyles.html). Not that clear from the answer, though.